# Laravel 4.1 Eloquent Relations with belongstoMany or morphToMany god know what

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading, relation

Programs has **Items** and **Uitems** table ( there can be many programs and many programs can have same or different items whereas items can be in different programs)

pivot table : has **items_id** and **items_type** where **items_id** can have '*id*' from either **items** or **uitems**

so if i were to list Programs::find(1)->with('Items', 'uItems') where if items_type ===user use **uitems**  else use **items**  i need something like this!

I have Programs table:

```
id  user_id name    description 
1   2   x workouti  High intensity
2   1   yn workouti low intensity
3   2   c workouti  massive workout
4   2   b oldm abi  sfsdf
```

I have a pivot table seen in picture below.
[image: The structure of my pivot table]

Programs table has a relation with 2 tables below

1. items "core" -->    id  | category_id | name | description
2. Uitems "user" -->  id | user_id | name | description

If you look at the pivot table i have two columns named **items_id** and **items_type** those two represent items and uitems table SO;

```
if(items_type === 'user') then pull info from Uitems as well as;
if(items_type === 'core') then pull info from items.
```

What i have tried was to;

```
Route::get('ws/{id?}', function($id)
{    
    $workouts = array('Monday'=>'', 'Tuesday'=>'', 'Wednesday'=>'', 'Thursday'=>'', 'Friday'=>'', 'Saturday'=>'', 'Sunday'=>'');
    $days = Days::all()->lists("name", "id");
        foreach($days as $dayKey => $day)
        {
            foreach($programs = Programs::find($id)->items()->wherePivot('days_id', $dayKey)->orderBy('sorts_id', 'ASC')->get() as $prokey => $program)
            {
                $program->settings = Settings::find($program->pivot->settings_id)->toArray();

                if($program->pivot->items_type ==='core')
                {
                   $program->items = Items::find($program->pivot->items_id)->toArray();
                }else if ($program->pivot->items_type ==='user')
                {
                   $program->items = Uitems::find($program->pivot->items_id)->toArray();
                   $program->by    =User::find(Uitems::find($program->pivot->items_id)->user_id)->toArray();
                }
                $workouts[$day][] = $program->toArray();
            }
        }


        $program = json_encode($workouts);
        return $program;

});
```

But this code results in 39 query attemps to the mysql which is not cool at all.
Which provides me exactly what i want with a weak performance:

[image]

Where is says by:oguzhan Piskin has the info from Uitems whereas others from Items

I need to accomplish this using Eloquent's Eager loading. Also query builder is find but my priority is on eager loading with Eloquent. 
Any help or clue highly appriciated!

Programs model:

```
class Programs extends Eloquent
```

{
    protected $table = "programs";

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Items')->withPivot('settings_id', 'days_id', 'sorts_id', 'id', 'items_type', 'items_id');
}
```

since i reach data using programs i was only using items to reach the data but when uitems data joins the challange in the pivot table i cant use both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like : 
Read more [here about eager loading constrains](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Edit your model :

```
public function items() 
{ 
return $this->belongsToMany('Items')->wherePivot('items_type', 'core')->withPivot('settings_id', 'days_id', 'sorts_id', 'id', 'items_type', 'items_id') 
}
public function uitems() 
{ 
return $this->belongsToMany('Items')->wherePivot('items_type', 'users')->withPivot('settings_id', 'days_id', 'sorts_id', 'id', 'items_type', 'items_id') 
}
```

And in your controller :

```
    <?php
    Route::get('ws/{id?}', function($id)
    {    
        $workouts = array('Monday'=>'', 'Tuesday'=>'', 'Wednesday'=>'', 'Thursday'=>'', 'Friday'=>'', 'Saturday'=>'', 'Sunday'=>'');
        $days = Days::all()->lists("name", "id");
        $program = Programs::find($id)->with('items','items');
?>
```

Hope i understood correctly what you wanted. Please let me know

Comment: Error: "syntax error, unexpected 'uses' (T_STRING), expecting '{'" 
$itemsConstrain = function($query) uses ($dayKey){

                $query->wherePivot('days_id', $dayKey)
                $query->wherePivot('items_type', 'core');
                $query->orderBy('sorts_id', 'ASC');

            };

Comment: i tried 'use' as well tryng debug it. this time it says 
syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: at what line? Also. you have only 1 product with that $id. no ?

Comment: ohh wait! Days model only gives id:1 name: monday and so on 
so there is no other data in it. i use those days to only categorize the main data which  the real data is in pivot table and i reach it Using something like Programs::find(1)->items()->get() this would list all the items with its pivots but only items not uitems

Comment: Because you are using the same items_id for Items and UItems, it's a little harder to do this, but not impossible :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51048/discussion-between-seblaze-and-oguzhan-piskin)

Comment: yes exactly, when i join Uitems it searches for Uitems_id then which does not exist in this case :)

Comment: please join in chat , it's way easier

Comment: sorry I could not come back due my busy schedule and school work also. Umm sort of, But turns out that i have to design an array in the server-side using nested foreachs. Thinking that whatever solution i come up with, will end up with numbers of mysql queries anyway. So i thought about different approach since this is a rest app. I can push all the necessary data with maybe max of 8 mysql queries and design my data model in the client side using angular. What do you think ? @seblaze